# Adjoint definition and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

> [image]

Can someone explain the last equality?

Isn't it $\overline{(Te_j, e_i)} = (e_i, Te_j)$? How is this the definition of adjoint

Comment: There's definitely an error.

Comment: probably there is more context about the cited statement, otherwise it doesnt make sense by itself.

Comment: @Masacroso, https://math.berkeley.edu/~peyam/Math110Sp13/Handouts/Normal%20Operators.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a typo in the quoted formula.
The second equality should indeed read $\overline{(Te_j, e_i)} = (e_i, Te_j)$, which is just the symmetry property of the complex inner product.

The first equality should read $(T^*e_i, e_j)=\overline{(Te_j, e_i)}$, which follows from the definition of matrix elements and the elementwise definition of adjoint: $(T^*)_{ij}=\overline{(T)_{ji}}$.

Correcting these two mistakes makes it reasonable.
Of course something else may have been intended; I can only guess from that amount of context.
Looking at [the source provided by the OP](https://math.berkeley.edu/~peyam/Math110Sp13/Handouts/Normal%20Operators.pdf), it seems that there are indeed two typos in the same formula.

The adjoint $T^*$ of $T$ is the one and only linear operator which satisfies $(T^*e_i, e_j)=(e_i, Te_j)$.
This is the "modern day definition of adjoint" meant in the text.
More typically, the adjoint is defined so that $(T^*a, b)=(a, Tb)$ for all vectors $a$ and $b$, but it is enough to demand that it holds for the basis.

Comment: it is not the first equality also wrong? That is $$\langle T^*e_j,e_i\rangle=\langle e_j,Te_i\rangle\neq\langle e_i,Te_j\rangle=\overline{\langle Te_j,e_i\rangle}$$

Comment: I got it from https://math.berkeley.edu/~peyam/Math110Sp13/Handouts/Normal%20Operators.pdf 2nd explanation

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks! I updated the answer. There was indeed a typo in the first half, too.

Comment: @Hawk I took a look, and it indeed looks like an unfortunate double typo in the formula. The definition of adjoints element by element is alluded to, but perhaps it was not mentioned explicitly.